# How to add the number of rows of the first table to another with the condition

Tags: mysql, sql

There are two tables:

```
####comments####     ####news######
#cid#news_id#         #id##comm_num#  
#1##1#               #1###2#
#2##1#               #2###1#
#3##2#               #3###3#
```

I try to count and put the number of comments from the table 'comments' into the table 'news', but I get the wrong result. Why?

```
UPDATE news JOIN comments ON news.id = comments.news_id SET 
news.comm_num = ( SELECT COUNT( * ) 
FROM comments WHERE comments.news_id > 123)
WHERE news.id > 123
```

'comments.news_id' = 'id' of commented news from table 'news'

I wrote a working solution for particular cases, but I can’t figure out how to make a request with a condition larger than.

```
UPDATE news a 
SET comm_num = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                FROM comments c 
                WHERE c.news_id = 123) 
WHERE a.id = 123
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE news n 
    SET comm_num = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                    FROM comments c 
                    WHERE c.news_id = n.id
                   ) ;
```

I am not sure what the condition `WHERE news.id > 123` is for.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the count of total comments on a news using a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html). Join this back to the `news` table on the `news_id` and update the values accordingly.

We use `LEFT JOIN` to handle the case where there is no comments on a news. And, [`Coalesce()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function is used to change `null` to 0 (in case of no comments).

```
UPDATE news a 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT news_id, COUNT(*) AS comm_num 
           FROM comments 
           GROUP BY news_id) b 
  ON b.news_id = a.id 
SET a.comm_num = COALESCE(b.comm_num,0)
```

If you want to update only those `news` where `id` is more than 123; you can add the conditions as follows:

```
UPDATE news a 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT news_id, COUNT(*) AS comm_num 
           FROM comments 
           WHERE news_id > 123 -- add condition to Derived Table
           GROUP BY news_id) b 
  ON b.news_id = a.id 
WHERE a.id > 123 -- add condition here also to avoid updating id <= 123
SET a.comm_num = COALESCE(b.comm_num,0)
```